# how to write out this equation on Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this equation that my manager would like to use on Mathematica, but I've only been learning how to use Mathematica for a few hours.

I need to solve for Ax and also plot a graph.  Please help...... Thank you!!!

At  =  (Ao - Ax)e-kt  +  Ax

k = the slope
A0 = the initial or the starting value is 0.837

```
Table       
t           At
0           0.837
50          0.763
100         0.699
150         0.647
200         0.602
250         0.563
300         0.532
350         0.505
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{0, 0.837}, {50, 0.763}, {100, 0.699}, {150, 0.647}, {200, 0.602}, 
        {250, 0.563}, {300, 0.532}, {350, 0.505}};

With[{Ao = 0.837},
 p = NonlinearModelFit[data, (Ao - Ax) Exp[-k t] + Ax, {Ax, {k, 1/200}}, t]
 ]

Show[
 ListPlot[data],
 Plot[p["BestFit"], {t, 0, 350}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I provided a starting value for the value of `k` (1/200) that kept the search for the best fit a bit on its track. With the exponent there it's pretty easy to derail the fit and end up with huge numbers.

Comment: @Margaret Before your manager provides you with a new assignment please try to read some introductory text on Mathematica. It is not the goal of the site to be a replacement of the manual.

Comment: isn't this answer a high level for newbie.

Comment: @Algohi Not much here that can be dumbed down. Perhaps, the With could have been skipped in favor of just a plain assignment, but that would be it basically. `FindFit` instead of `NonlinearModelFit` would require extra steps.

Comment: I see. Perhaps a simple table and listplot could do it. +1 anyway.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  I really do appreciate your time :).